# Move item to top of screen after adding fast scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I successfully added fast scrolling in my application using third part code. Which draw alphabets on right side of screen and give me the letter that is clicked then i put following code to move to that block. Which is working fine. Following is my code :

```
mSideBarView.setOnTouchLetterChangeListener(new WaveSideBarView.OnTouchLetterChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLetterChange(String letter) {
            //int pos = adapter.getLetterPosition(letter);
            char c=letter.charAt(0);

            if(c=='#'){

                Contact con = mAllContactlist.get(0);
                char firstCharacter = mAllContactlist.get(0).getmName().charAt(0);

                if((firstCharacter >= '0' && firstCharacter <= '9'))
                    mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
            }
            else{
                int pos =getLetterPosition(c);
                if (pos != -1) {
                    mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(pos);

                }
            }
        }
    });
```

As you can see i am using scrolltoposition which took view to that particular recyclerview cell. But that cell not on top of screen as in default app. To get clear i added images. [image: First Image[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpnSI.png)

I pressed U and it moved to U tab which is ok but i want to show this on top of screen like default app do. Following is screenshot of default phone book app.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use function scrollToPositionWithOffset instead of scrollToPosition in RecyclerView for this:

```
//Scroll item pos to 0 pixels from the top
linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(pos, 0);
```